# Searching for live natural soundscapes

Tags: live, live-sound, nature-recording, nature, soundscapes

I'm looking for live and all day long soundscapes of real natural places.
I know these things are rare but maybe someone knows sites with this kind material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to find a youtube livestream of a place, that you like and capture the video off of that.

Example Video:

And here is a tutorial of how to capture the video (and more importantly the sound): https://acethinker.com/desktop-recorder/record-youtube-live-stream.html

Here is a site that I found that curates quite a few nature livestreams: https://explore.org/livecams/ (which is actually really cool, so thanks for asking the question, otherwise I wouldn't have find that)

The other more obvious approach is to go to https://splice.com/ pay 10$ for one month and search for 'birds' or 'ocean' and download short loops there. But they are only a few seconds to a few minutes, so that doesn't answer your question.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Great!! This is really a great idea! It's definitely easier to find live cams of natural places !!!! Thank you very very much!!!!